# how to read all child nodes values and use them in firebase android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is my Database in Firebase

[image]

I want to get the values of Students under Courses 
and then I want to delete the course name under courses in users(that username match the values I got from Courses/Students ) 
after clicking on a button

[image]

This is my code

```
DatabaseReference mCourseDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Courses").child(courseModel.getCourseName());
    final DatabaseReference mStudentDB = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
    mCourseDatabaseReference.child("Students").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for(final DataSnapshot snapshot1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                final User student = snapshot1.getValue(User.class);
                mStudentDB.orderByChild("userName").equalTo(student.getUserName()).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        for (DataSnapshot data: dataSnapshot.getChildren())
                        {
                            String stuserkey = data.getKey();
                            mStudentDB.child(stuserkey).child("Courses").child(courseModel.getCourseName()).removeValue();
                        }
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) { }});
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) { }});
```

but it doesn't work.
can you help me, please?
thanks.

Comment: When you say it doesn't work, what specifically happens?

Comment: nothing happens after clicking on the button .. the course under Users (Users/keyuid/Courses) is not deleted from database

Comment: There is quite a lot of code here. If you set a breakpoint on the first line *inside* each `onDataChange`, you can see if that line gets executed when you run it in a debugger. If so: check of all the lines do what you expect them to do. If not, which line is behaving different from your expectation?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I got this : dataSnapshot = {Datasnapshot@7102} "Datasnapshot { key = Students, value = null } 
I don't know why value is null it should get the child values under Students

Comment: So it sounds like `courseModel.getCourseName()` is not giving you the value you expect. Try it with a hard-coded value, such as `mCourseDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Courses").child("12955");`